# how to work with arbitrarily large numbers in cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to implement the miller-rabin algorithm in cython to check the primality of very large primes. On the other hand, I'm not sure how to store and use very large numbers (i.e 2^2048) in cython. Is there an easy way to work with arbitrarily large numbers in cython?

Comment: Integers have unlimited precision in Python, so just use them

Comment: Using python integer works in cython but it won't get any substantial speed up. Was hoping for a method that uses cython directly.

Comment: A (fairly ugly) alternative could be to wrap a C library in cython that works with unlimited precision integers such as [gmp](https://gmplib.org/). Have not worked with this before but will certainly not be as easy to use as python integers.

Answer (score 2):

`gmpy` seems to have Cython bindings:

https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cython.html